# WordPress blog responsiveness

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, smartphone

Our [company website](http://www.bluehouse-agency.com) was built with WordPress + [Forest](http://codestag.com/themes/forest/) theme.

To get a full width blog, we had to remove the sidebar from the relevant templates and add the following custom CSS:

```
blog .site-content, .single .site-content  { width: 70%; max-width: 70%; margin: auto; }
```

This works fine on desktop and most of other devices and screen sizes.

However, the display is not very nice on smartphones, because of too big margins on both sides.

So, we tried to implement the following custom CSS to fix that, but it did not seem to alter the display on smartphones:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) .blog .site-content, .single .site-content  { width: 90%; max-width: 90%; margin: auto; }
```

Any idea of what is wrong here and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Min-width 992px!? I don't know many smartphones that have that as a minimum width. Check out the iphone cheat sheets for min width recommendations and try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted smaller margins on smaller displays, it should have been

```
@media (max-width: 992px) {
   .blog .site-content, .single .site-content { 
        width: 90%; max-width: 90%; margin: auto; 
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrei, it totally fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your `@media` code is missing some curly braces (`{` and `}`), and you need to use `max-width`, not `min-width`. I typically add `@media handheld` to my mobile CSS as well.

```
@media (max-width: 992px),
@media handheld {
    .blog .site-content, .single .site-content { 
        width: 90%; max-width: 90%; margin: auto; 
    }
}
```